# How to add auto navbar expand on mouse hover? on this site

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the website I'm developing now I have a problem with how to auto navbar expand on mouse hover on this site http://www.kasuncfernando.tk/dls/index.html can you guys inspect it and tell me what to do or what to add, thank you

[how to set navbar auto-expand on mouse hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M96n.png)

Comment: Hi:) It's not clear what you'd like to expand.

Comment: @Azu main navbar on this site http://www.kasuncfernando.tk/dls/index.html how to set it when i drag mouse point into the navbar section the sub menus will need to be auto-expanded

Comment: So you'd like to expand the dropdown menus on hover, not on click?

Comment: @Azu yes thats i need

Comment: This can be done, but now the menus are controlled by Javascript.

Comment: @Azu ohh then what can we do for it?

Comment: @Kasun See my answer

Comment: @Azu Thank you so Much it's working better now :D

Comment: @Whispored2001 thankyou so much you too your code helped me for auto expand sub menus in mobile view :D i noticed it

Comment: Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @tacoshy yeah, I understood. Thankyou you for your pieces of informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one item of the menu. Try this:

```css
.dropdown-menu.multi-level {
    display: none;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block  
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Admission <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
            <li><a href="btech_admission.html">B.Tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="mtech_admission.html">M.Tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="phd_admission.html">Ph.D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, check if it helps:

```css
.navbar-nav > li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```